# While deploying nextjs app throwing error: The "next export" command has been removed in favor of "output: export" in next.config.js

Tags: next.js, error-handling, deployment, next.js14

//next.config.js

```js
/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export',
  images: {
    unoptimized: true
  }
  // Optional: Change links `/me` -> `/me/` and emit `/me.html` -> `/me/index.html`
  // trailingSlash: true,
 
  // Optional: Prevent automatic `/me` -> `/me/`, instead preserve `href`
  // skipTrailingSlashRedirect: true,
 
  // Optional: Change the output directory `out` -> `dist`
  // distDir: 'dist',
}
 
module.exports = nextConfig
```

//package.json

```json
{
  "name": "dummy",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
   
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.20",
    "next": "14.0.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.4",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

I  tried by  adding  output: 'export' to next.config.js file, then "export: next export" to package.json file

Answer (score 3):

Starting from next@14 `next export` command was removed in favor of `output: "export"` in `next.config.js`.

#### To build static html pages:

1. Configure the output in `next.config.js`

```js
module.export = {
  output: "export",
  // ...
}
```

2. Use `next build` instead of `next export` to build your project.
   run `npm run build`

### read more at [the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports)

Answer (score 0):

check in your package.json as well and make sure the "build": "next build"  is only there under the scripts.  You could have something like "build": "next build && next export"

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue today, and thanks to [Ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18079514/ahmed-abdelbaset) comment I've been able to solve this issue.

In my case, I followed this guide: https://medium.com/frontendweb/how-to-deploy-a-nextjs-app-to-github-pages-1de4f6ed762e

There is a step where you configure the required yml file for the build, and all I did was comment the lines of the step that required the *next* *export* command. (I know that deleting them may be better but just in case :))

```yaml
       - name: Static HTML export with Next.js
         run: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.runner }} next export
```

Also, this was my next.config.js file:

```js
     /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */ 
    const nextConfig = {
    output: 'export',
    reactStrictMode: true,
    }
    module.exports = nextConfig
```